# Huawei mobile File Transfer to my computer doesnot work

Tags: applications

I used to transfer files but now I can't. The USB cable transfers from another Huawei, but from my Huawei mobile it doesn't. I turned debug **on**. Still my computer does not identify it.

Comment: Did you installed the drivers on your computer. Did you manage to change the mode in which phone acts when linked to computer (USB storage , MTP, PTP)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install the drivers?

If you didn't do this you should install Samsung Adb drivers, it might say Samsung, but it's for all devices. First install it from this link:

[(Samsung) Adb drivers](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201401/20140121132354500/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.33.0.exe)

After that:

1. Reboot your PC.
2. After the reboot press <kbd>[image]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `devmgmt.msc`.
3. Find the phone, do right click on it →  **Properties** →  **Update drivers**.
4. Select **Browse my computer** for drivers.
5. Select **Let me pick a driver from a list of installed drivers**.
6. Select "Adb drivers" (it might be called something different).
7. Select **Samsung Android Adb interface**.
8. Select Yes to continue (if you get a warning)

You're all set to copy.